# Segmentation Error when using basic_string.h +operator

Tags: c++, string, segmentation-fault

I have a simple code which is basically like the one below:

```
static  std::string const part1[] = {"Test1", "Test2", "Test3"};

static  std::string const part2[] = {"Pass", "Fail", "Retry"};

std::string test = part1[1] + part2[0];
```

I have included the `string` which in turn has the `basic_string.h`. I know that there is an overloaded `+`operator there. 
When I built this I got no errors but when I tried to run it, I got a segmentation error. 
The problem I noticed later is that if I simply try to print the array elements, I am seeing the same segmentation error. 
I don't see where the memory leak is happening. Any clues?

Comment: What compiler?  I get syntax errors with both clang & gcc trying to build your code.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake on the code when I placed it here. I have the data declared as: static std::string const part1[] = {"Test1", "Test2", "Test3"}; I am using eclipse in linux env.

Answer (score 0):

In c++ array declaration is not possible in the way you used in your code.

A Valid code example is

```
static  std::string const part1[] ={"Test1", "Test2", "Test3"};
static  std::string const part2[] = {"Pass", "Fail", "Retry"};

std::string test = part1[1] + part2[0];
```

Comment: This is how my code is, sorry I typed that out instead of copy pase and so the major type. The problem I noticed now is that if I simply try to print the array elements, I am seeing the segmentation error. That means the way my string is declared is incorrect? static  std::string const part1[] = {"Test1", "Test2", "Test3"};

Comment: No i think declaration is correct. verify your index for out of bound error